# Javascript Map through Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, mapping

I am able to print out tmdb_popularity but unable to map/print out with provider(netflix).
I believe I am mapping through {} incorrectly.
movie.offers[0].provider_id failed as well.

Also, is there a way to map out only scoring by 'provider_type:tmdb:score' > 8 for example?
Since tmdb:score is Object.value instead of key is it not feasible?

Thank you.

```
const JustWatch = require ("justwatch-api")

const netflixId = 8;

function print_result (name, result) {
    console.log(name+":");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
    console.log("\n\n\n\n");
}

(async function(){
    var justwatch = new JustWatch();

    var searchResult = await justwatch.search('a');

    searchResult.items.map(function(movie){
        if(movie.offers.provider_id == netflixId){
            print_result("search", searchResult)
        }
    })

     searchResult.items.map(function(movie){
         if(movie.tmdb_popularity > 20){
             print_result("search",searchResult)
         }
    })

}) ();
```

What the JSON data looks like from (JustWatch API)

```
{
    "total_results": 27468,
    "items": [
        {
            "jw_entity_id": "ts80908",
            "id": 80908,
            "title": "A Very English Scandal",
            "tmdb_popularity": 3.422,
            "object_type": "show",
            "offers": [
                {
                    "type": "aggregated",
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 9,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "urls": {
                        "standard_web": "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07DX9DKP5?camp=1789&creativeASIN=B07DX9DKP5&ie=UTF8&linkCode=xm2&tag=justwatch09-20",
                        "deeplink_android_tv": "intent://watch.amazon.com/watch?asin=B07DX9DKP5&time=0&territory=US#Intent;package=com.amazon.amazonvideo.livingroom;scheme=https;end"
                    },
                    "subtitle_languages": [
                        "en"
                    ],
                    "presentation_type": "sd",
                    "element_count": 1,
                    "new_element_count": 1,
                    "date_provider_id": "2019-09-14_9",
                    "date_created": "2019-09-14"
                },
                {
                    "type": "aggregated",
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 9,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "urls": {
                        "standard_web": "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07DX9DKP5?camp=1789&creativeASIN=B07DX9DKP5&ie=UTF8&linkCode=xm2&tag=justwatch09-20",
                        "deeplink_android_tv": "intent://watch.amazon.com/watch?asin=B07DX9DKP5&time=0&territory=US#Intent;package=com.amazon.amazonvideo.livingroom;scheme=https;end"
                    },
                    "subtitle_languages": [
                        "en"
                    ],
                    "presentation_type": "hd",
                    "element_count": 1,
                    "new_element_count": 1,
                    "date_provider_id": "2019-09-14_9",
                    "date_created": "2019-09-14"
                },
                {
                    "type": "aggregated",
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 9,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "urls": {
                        "standard_web": "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07DX8CSSQ?camp=1789&creativeASIN=B07DX8CSSQ&ie=UTF8&linkCode=xm2&tag=justwatch09-20",
                        "deeplink_android_tv": "intent://watch.amazon.com/watch?asin=B07DX8CSSQ&time=0&territory=US#Intent;package=com.amazon.amazonvideo.livingroom;scheme=https;end",
                        "deeplink_fire_tv": "intent://com.amazon.tv.launcher/detail?provider=aiv&providerId=B07DX8CSSQ#Intent;package=com.amazon.tv.launcher;scheme=amzn;end",
                        "deeplink_tvos": "aiv://aiv/watch?asin=B07DX8CSSQ&territory=US&time=auto"
                    },
                    "subtitle_languages": [
                        "en"
                    ],
                    "presentation_type": "4k",
                    "element_count": 1,
                    "new_element_count": 1,
                    "date_provider_id": "2019-09-06_9",
                    "date_created": "2019-09-06"
                }
            ],
            "scoring": [
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:score",
                    "value": 8.1
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "imdb:score",
                    "value": 7.8
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:popularity",
                    "value": 3.422
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "jw_entity_id": "tm205151",
            "id": 205151,
            "title": "Alpha",
            "full_path": "/us/movie/alpha-2015",
            "full_paths": {
                "MOVIE_DETAIL_OVERVIEW": "/us/movie/alpha-2015"
            },
            "poster": "/poster/139203407/{profile}",
            "original_release_year": 2015,
            "tmdb_popularity": 0.878,
            "object_type": "movie",
            "offers": [
                {
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 25,
                    "urls": {
                        "standard_web": "https://www.fandor.com/films/alpha"
                    },
                    "presentation_type": "hd",
                    "date_provider_id": "2016-06-13_25",
                    "date_created": "2016-06-13"
                },
                {
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 25,
                    "urls": {
                        "standard_web": "https://www.fandor.com/films/alpha"
                    },
                    "presentation_type": "sd",
                    "date_provider_id": "2016-06-13_25",
                    "date_created": "2016-06-13"
                },
                {
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 199,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "urls": {
                        "standard_web": "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01M7O3UQU?camp=1789&creativeASIN=B01M7O3UQU&ie=UTF8&linkCode=xm2&tag=justwatch09-20",
                        "deeplink_android_tv": "intent://watch.amazon.com/watch?asin=B01M7O3UQU&time=0&territory=US#Intent;package=com.amazon.amazonvideo.livingroom;scheme=https;end",
                        "deeplink_fire_tv": "intent://com.amazon.tv.launcher/detail?provider=aiv&providerId=B01M7O3UQU#Intent;package=com.amazon.tv.launcher;scheme=amzn;end",
                        "deeplink_tvos": "aiv://aiv/watch?asin=B01M7O3UQU&territory=US&time=auto"
                    },
                    "presentation_type": "sd",
                    "date_provider_id": "2019-06-19_199",
                    "date_created": "2019-06-19"
                }
            ],
            "scoring": [
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:popularity",
                    "value": 0.878
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:id",
                    "value": 333465
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:score",
                    "value": 7
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "imdb:score",
                    "value": 7.7
                }
            ]
        },
        ....
```

Comment: `movie.offers` is an array, it will need another loop like used for `searchResult.items`

Comment: also `.map()` is used to return a new array which isn't being used in the example code, you could use `.forEach()` instead.

Comment: I agree with @Matt. It might be better for you to more clearly define what you are trying to do with the JSON data. Regarding your second question, I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but iterating over the scoring array to find the score corresponding to provider_type: "tmbd_score" should be quiet straight forward.

Comment: @marksy_91 How would I do that? Do I use object keys/values function?

Answer (score 0):

Here Try this

```
searchResult.items.map(function(movie){
        movie.offers.forEach(offer => {
          if(offer.provider_id == netflixId){
             print_result("search", searchResult)
          }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is better here instead of `map` as you are not returning in map function. Use find function to search for offer.

```
searchResult.items.forEach(function(movie) {
    const offer = movie.offers.find(offer => offer.provider_id == netflixId);
    if(offer){
        print_result("search", movie)
        print_result("offer", offer)
    }
})
```